# In trying to test promises, I am making some mistake. These tests should fail

Tags: javascript, promise, jasmine, chai

All these specs run fine even when they shouldn't.  Just take a look at the ridiculous answers given by the delay function, please.  I'm sorry i tried to figure out how to format the code more readably but failed.

Test spec:

```
describe("delay", function () {

  var chai = require("chai");
  var expect = chai.expect;
  var chaiAsPromised = require("chai-as-promised");
  chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

  var Calculator = require('C:/BaseCalculators/Calculator');
  var delay = require('C:/BaseCalculators/delay');
  var calculator;

  beforeEach(function () {
    calculator = new Calculator();
  });

  it("returns a promise", function () {
  var willAdd = delay( 100, calculator, 'add', [ 1, 1 ] );
  expect( willAdd ).to.be.instanceOf( Promise );
  expect( willAdd ).to.be.fulfilled;
  });

  it("delays execution", function () {
    expect( delay( 1000, calculator, 'add', [ 10, 5 ] ) ).to.eventually.equal( 150 );
    expect( delay( 500, calculator, 'subtract', [ 9, 5 ] ) ).to.eventually.equal( 14 );
    });

  it("cannot execute functions that do not exist", function () {
    expect( delay( 1000, calculator, 'sqrt', [ 2, 2 ] ) ).to.be.rejected;
  });
});
```

Calulator seems to work fine with its' own tests but I can add more code if required.  Here is the delay function which I believe is the problem:

```
    delay = function (ms, obj, methodName, params) {
  var p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {      
        var data = obj[methodName](...params);
        console.log(data);
        p.resolve(data);
      }, ms);   
    }
  )
  return p;
}; 

module.exports = delay;
```

Comment: Can you pare this down to just one line, like `expect(Promise.resolve(5)).to.eventually.equal(6)`?

Comment: Yes, I tried that and it worked: {UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): AssertionError: expected 5 to equal 6}

Comment: There must be something wrong with my delay function....

Comment: That doesn’t sound very working. Looks like [chai-as-promised returns a promise from its assertions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai-as-promised), and you should `await` on it. (`await expect(willAdd).to.be.fulfilled`, in an `async function () {`.)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is that I was using Jasmine, which is just not very good for asynchronous tests, apparently.  I created a new project, copied over all the tests and js app files, and installed only mocha, chai, and chai-as-promised then configured this portion of my package.json as follows:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha --reporter spec"
```

After that, running "npm test" everything started working like a charm.  Not sure why the negative rep for my question, can I get some of that back for finding this solution that others might find useful?

Comment: You were using chai-as-promised wrong, though. Read the README: https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai-as-promised See all the `return`s? That’s how promises work. If you still don’t have them, it could just be working by coincidence.